# Is it possible to use managed property which is from type lookup?

Tags: managed-property, display-template

I have content search webpart. In this webpart I have edited the mapped properties. I see my custom columns, but not from type "lookup". Is it possible to select a lookup field as managed property to show it in my item template?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You need to create manual the crawled property and the managed property. Map them together. Do a full crawl and you can use it in the display template.